# Load just an ID of href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to load just an ID of a url, instead of loading the entire page.

I was trying the following:

```
var page = $(this).attr('href', #organisation);
```

All I need from that page is what is inside `#organisation`
This will be used for multiple pages, so I can't paste the url, I have to use `href`

Comment: It's the first question I post, so I don't know why I'm getting -4 votes...

Comment: what are you actually wanting? It's unclear as to what you're asking (hence the downvotes) - also you're applying a DOM manipulation function to a variable - I'm not sure this is even possible ... (this way at least )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load only Id by given below code.
First declare the Url of page & then load only Id from that url.
Here `.wide_main` is where we want to display.

```
var page_url = $(this).attr("href")
$(".wide_main").load( page_url + ' #Id');
```